# Help identifying clasuses, sentence structure

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses

I'm a first time poster, so please let me know if I am posting in the wrong place! I am trying to break down the sentence structure of this sentence. Specifically, how commas are used in the following sentence-

**When Annemarie flailed, sleeping, I was the one who always shook her until she sat up, sheet-tangled, still half-caught in her dream.**

This is what I have so far -

When Annemarie flailed - subordinate adverb clause
Sleeping - ???
I was the one who always shook her - independent clause
until she sat up - subordinate adverb clause
sheet-tangled - subordinate adverb clause modifying the "until" clause????
still caught in her sleep - ????

Any help would be appreciated! This is from R.O. Kwon's short shory [Helping](https://tinhouse.com/helping/)